# Why is an incompressible isotropic elastic medium always a liquid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, symmetry, elasticity

This was a claim made by my professor in my mechanical metallurgy class. I don't see how it is true. I could very well have a solid (which is incompressible) and have isotropic properties. We deal with such types of materials every day.

I have no idea as to how to even begin approaching this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: All real solids and liquids are compressible. An amorphous solid or glass would be isotropic and similar to a liquid (particularly the glass, of course).

Comment: I think we might be dealing with ideal behaviors here, not real.

Comment: Indeed. The second sentence still stands.

Comment: How does it prove the given statement. We want to see why liquids are the only incompressible isotropic elastic mediums.

Comment: I agree with your assessment.  I am thinking particularly of elastomers like rubber which are very nearly incompressible.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropic_solid) has some hints on how to prove the inverse: "there is no isotropic solid" -- and suggests amorphous solids are only isotropic over a particular length scale. I suppose if something isn't a solid, then it must be a fluid -- how to show that it must be a liquid instead of a gas, not sure about. Unless it hinges on the word "elastic" maybe.

Comment: It does seem exceedingly nit-picky though... and kind of unfair to assume it's ideal-enough for it to be incompressible but not ideal enough that anisotropy due to atomic orientations or finite atom sizes need to be considered relevant.

Comment: @Sayantan Your most recent edit has made a perfectly reasonable question incomprehensible.  I highly suggest rolling back this edit, or at least modifying it to be more clear.

Comment: I have taken the freedom to rollback to your original version. The last version was incomprehensible indeed, while the original was interesting.

Answer (score 3):

A common polycrystalline metal is isotropic if it is not cold worked. The average diameter of typical steel grains is between 0.01 to 0.1 mm.

As they have random orientations, we can use the law of large numbers to consider any macroscopic part isotropic.

If a metal rod is placed in a cylindrical cavity with tight tolerances and compressed, it is as incompressible as a liquid in the same situation.

So, pratically I think that most of the metal objects that surround us can be taken as incompressible and isotropic elastic materials.

Comment: would they be also essentially incompressible even after having become strained beyond their yield?

Comment: @hyportnex yes, the plastic deformation is a shear driven process, where the crystallographic planes slides, due to dislocations movement.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your professor is stringing together some typical idealizations and assumptions but in somewhat questionable way.

1. We often assume that liquids are incompressible because their shear modulus is far, far less than their bulk modulus. But we make the same assumption for elastomers for the same reason. We also often assume that ductile materials are incompressible while plastically deforming for a related reason: their shear deformation is far, far greater than their dilatation. No real material is incompressible.
2. We often idealize liquids as being isotropic. But we make the same assumption for amorphous solids and small-grained polycrystalline materials without a prevailing orientation. I believe that all real materials exhibit *some* degree of short-range order and anisotropy, although for a liquid, any short-range order would average out to zero over time because the atoms are free to rearrange. You can't say this about a frozen supercooled liquid.

So perhaps what your professor meant is this: Of the materials that we tend to idealize as incompressible, the only state that exhibits an temporally average anisotropy of zero at any location is the ideal liquid state.